# Java stream bloquea archivo

Tags: java, stream

Tengo esta función que busca una linea en un archivo y la elimina. El caso es que algún stream queda abierto y no me permite renombrar el archivo.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;

public class Test {
    public void updateAttrib(MailInfo m) throws IOException {

        File inputFile = new File(Directory.directory+"\\"+User.user+"\\mails.txt");
        File tempFile = new File(Directory.directory+"\\"+User.user+"\\mailstmp.txt");

        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            try {
                RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(tempFile,"rw");
                raf.close();
                Files.delete(tempFile.toPath());
            } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        }

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(inputFile);
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(tempFile);
        try {
            BufferedReader reader;
            reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
            BufferedWriter writer;
            writer = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            try {

            String lineToRemove = m.getNombre();
            String currentLine;

                while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                    if(trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) continue;
                    writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }

            } finally {
                reader.close();
                writer.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException ioe) {
        } finally {
            fr.close();
            fw.close();
        }

        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
}
```

Comment: Veo que estás ignorando las excepciones. Por lo menos imprime el stacktrace de c/u para que veas dónde puede estar el error concreto. Si es el caso de streams que dices, puede que uno de los archivos esté abierto durante la ejecución de ese fragmento de código.

Comment: Java tiene un problema con el manejo de archivos (renameTo) en Windows, te recomiendo si usas Java 7 utilizar el método Files.move
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.CopyOption...)

Comment: Como se ha dicho en los otros comentarios, puedes probar con `move`. [Aquí tienes un ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5451161/5587982). Y también optimiza el código, estoy viendo un `try` sin `catch`. El `try` que tiene `catch` no hace nada con la excepción y el último `catch` parece no cerrarse. Necesitas revisar todo eso.

Comment: Gracias, usar move funcionó.

Comment: Adicional a los comentarios anteriores, tampoco es recomendable el uso de try anidados, en esa caso es mejor separar funcionalidades en metodos independientes, y por otro lado usar `try` con `resources`

Answer (score 0):

Te limpié el código para que se maneje correctamente los close y las excepciones se propaguen para que puedas ver el error:

```
public class Test {
    public void updateAttrib(MailInfo m) throws IOException {

        File inputFile = new File(Directory.directory+"\\"+User.user+"\\mails.txt");
        File tempFile = new File(Directory.directory+"\\"+User.user+"\\mailstmp.txt");

        if (tempFile.exists()) {
            try (RandomAccessFile raf=new RandomAccessFile(tempFile,"rw")) {
                Files.delete(tempFile.toPath());
            } 
        }

        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile))) {
            try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile))) {
  
               String lineToRemove = m.getNombre();
               String currentLine = null;

               while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
                    if(trimmedLine.contains(lineToRemove)) continue;
                    writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                }

         }

        boolean successful = tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);
    }
}
```

En tu ejemplo, como suprimías excepciones los errores se escondían y no podías ver la causa de tus problemas.